# Maya Python - Two Questions about Dictionaries and Menus

Tags: python, maya, execute

Q1 - How can i refresh a dictionary to relist files from a directory showing up on a menu?

Q2 - How can you execute a script that is listed as a dictionary file from a menu?

this is what I have so far

```
    import os
    import maya.cmds as cmds
    from functools import partial

    # Delete the Menu if it already exists
    if cmds.menu('PadraigsTools', exists = True):
        cmds.deleteUI('PadraigsTools')

    #Creating the GUI
    PadraigsTools=cmds.menu('PadraigsTools', p='MayaWindow', label='PadraigsTools')

    # The Refresh Function / Refresh the scripts
    cmds.menuItem(p=PadraigsTools, l="Refresh" ) #refresh root_dict? 
    cmds.menuItem(p=PadraigsTools, d=1)

    # Browse through Directories
    cmds.menuItem(p=PadraigsTools, l="Change")
    cmds.menuItem(p=PadraigsTools, d=1)

    Python = cmds.menuItem("Python",subMenu=1, label='Python')
    cmds.setParent(Python, menu=True )

    Mel = cmds.menuItem("Mel", subMenu=1, label='Mel', p='PadraigsTools')
    cmds.setParent( Mel, menu=True)

    #TODO Plugins and Other Files Association
    '''Plugins = cmds.menuItem("Plugins", subMenu=1, label='Plugins', p='PadraigsTools')
    cmds.setParent( Plugins, menu=True)

    Other = cmds.menuItem("Other", subMenu=1, label='Other', p='PadraigsTools')
    cmds.setParent( Other, menu=True)'''

    # Searching for Mel and Python Files
    def find_files(root, extensions = ('mel', 'py')):
        def clean_path(*p):
            return "/".join(p).replace('\\', '/')

        for root, _, files in os.walk(root):
            used = [f for f in files if f.split(".")[-1] in extensions]
            for u in used:
                yield clean_path(root, u)
    # Creating a dictionary with given files
    def relativize(abs, roots):
        low_roots = map (str.lower, roots) # all lower for comparison
        for root, low_root in zip(roots,low_roots):
            if abs.lower().startswith(low_root):
                return root, abs[len(root):]
        return "", abs

    relative_paths = find_files('C:/Users/OCuinn/Dropbox/Maya Scripts/')

    root_dict = {}
    for item in relative_paths :
        folders, files = relativize(item, ('C:/Users/OCuinn/Dropbox/Maya Scripts/Python Code','C:/Users/OCuinn/Dropbox/Maya Scripts/Mel Code', 'C:/Users/OCuinn/Dropbox/Maya Scripts'))
        if not folders in root_dict:
            root_dict[folders] = []
        root_dict[folders].append(files)

    # call this on every button selection
    def test(filepath, ignore):
        # maya will send "test(name, False)"; we just ignore the 'False'
       print "Here is where I would reload", filepath

    for name in folder_names:
        PadraigsTools = name
        if PadraigsTools:
            PadraigsTools = PadraigsTools.split("/")[-2] # we used trailing slashes
        else:
            PadraigsTools = "root"
        file_names = root_dict[name]
        file_names.sort()
        for fn in file_names: # parent py and mel files to submenus
            if fn.endswith(".py"):

#This is the part I am stuck on I am trying to figure out how to execute the showing fn py or mel file.                                  
                command = "import " + fn[0] + '/' + fn[0] + '.' + fn[0]+ '()'
                cmds.menuItem(label = fn, p="Python", c=command)
            else:
                if fn.endswith(".mel"):
                        cmds.menuItem(label = fn, p="Mel", )
```

thanks
-padraig

Comment: This seems incomplete or garbled - did you hit send too early? Needs some clarification

Comment: I added the entire script. If there is a more Pythonic way of setting this up can you explain how i would go about it please?

Comment: for updating the dictionary, I thought i would of been able to get away with `update.dict(root_dict)` but that didnt work out so I am looking for a better way other than reloading the entire script from inside itself, which i think can only be done if the UI is stated as a module but this isnt my case

Answer (score 0):

If what you really need is a way to execute arbitrary files:

In mel its just calling `source "path/to/file.mel"`.

In python the usual method is to use the [`runpy` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/runpy.html).  Since modules can run code when imported, you can just leave code lying around loose in the file and it will be executed when you call `runpy.run_path()` on the absolute path of the .py file.  However Runpy does a little magic to make them not pollute the main python namespace, so if you're using the common python

```
if __name___ = '__main__':
   do_something()
```

idiom it will break, because code executed from `run_path` will not be in the `__main__` scope.  Instead it's in a special scope called `<run_path>`, so if you want to do things that only happen when run this way you can put them into a block like this:

```
if __name___ = '<run_path>':
   do_something_for_dynamic_load_only()
```

To simplify your code you should just first make two functions, one for loading mel and the other python, then choose the correct function based on extension:

```
import maya.mel as mel
import runpy

def load_mel(filename):
   mel.eval('source "%s"' % filename)

def load_py(filename):
   runpy.run_path(filename)

def load_script(filename):
   ext = filename.split(".")[-1].lower()
   if ext == "mel":
      load_mel(filename)
      return
   if ext == "py":
      load_py(filename)
      return
   cmds.warning("unable to execute file %s" % filename)
```

Then you can just build all of your menus using the same command but different filepaths.

In general, though, this kind of thing should be reserved for 'plugin' style extension of your toolkit, not as the main way of accessing functionality. You're not going to be able to share or reuse code loaded in these fashions, instead you'll just run it and get whatever happens.  Plus you will only get one function per file, or at least you will have to do lots of work to figure out what's in there.

Comment: That's exactly what the Senior TD mentioned to me, He said something about it being a part of a mainframe in the plugin. Anyway I'll give your code a check out and see how it goes. P.S. would this arbitrarily pick up mel and py files from the listed directories hard coded?

Comment: One more thing, Is there a way of getting a refresh on the dictionary?